# Error while running multipass launch

Tags: multipass

I'm new to ubuntu. I want to lunch multipass but it gives low disk space error. I have enough space in my hard disk. Thank you

Error message : launch failed: Available disk (541548544 bytes) below minimum for this image (2361393152 bytes)

Release detail:
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
[space detail find here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acjP6.png)

Comment: Description: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release: 20.04

sorry comment section does not allow to write more than 500 character. if I can provide space detail of specific directory

Comment: @guiverc hope this help to figure out

Comment: You've not said if this is a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop or Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server install, but the snap packages imply it's a desktop install; where the recommended minimum disk allocation is 25GB (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)  but you've allocated 19GB so lack of disk space is expected - and your issue.  The error message is exactly correct; 2361393152 bytes required but you've only 1.1 GB available so are 541548544 short.  If you don't allocate the recommended minimum space you need to keep your system extremely lean.